# FileHelper attributes limitied to fields/members only

Tags: filehelpers

I use the FieldQuoted attribute in my form class.  I noticed that I cannot put this attribute on properties.  It only allows it on members/fields.  Is there a reason for this? Can this be expanded to allow for properties?

Reason I ask is that I use this class in other places that are property friendly but not member friendly at all (e.g. MVC model binder).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Allow Properties instead of fields #67](https://github.com/MarcosMeli/FileHelpers/issues/67)

> Yes the library started with fields in 2004 mostly because if you
>   support properties you must to ensure that are writable, can throw
>   errors, can slow down assignment with custom code, also the reflection
>   of .net 1.1 were incredible slow and dynamic code generation for
>   fields was easy to implement
>
> Later for backward compatibility and lazyness I didn't support
>   properties, now autoproperties work better thanks to work in this PR
>   [#170](https://github.com/MarcosMeli/FileHelpers/pull/170)
>
> But we must to do the effort and support full properties and try to
>   make a little impact in the previous code to avoid weird errors, maybe
>   with new record classes

There seem to have been some changes made against [Autoproperties full support #170](https://github.com/MarcosMeli/FileHelpers/pull/170) but this hasn't been included in the release yet. It only seems to be available on the master branch.

> I will be merging this but later I will change the way it works to
>   avoid use of both autoproperties and fields and also to allow
>   properties in the general way, but your implementation make the use of
>   autoproperties a simple task

If you're not happy with using that, I would suggest just creating a separate class for the import/export to mirror your existing class but using fields, as suggested by the accepted answer to [Formatting properties with FileHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14761076/formatting-properties-with-filehelper). Probably the safest bet for now until they get released.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers to the PRs.  Indeed the master branch has the fix.  I guess just have to wait for the next release.  In the meantime, I think I'll duplicate the class with properties for non-filehelper purposes as suggested.  Not ideal but I'll consolidate once the feature is released.